# Nested resource issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am struggling to pass an id successfully into my URL for the nested resource I have set up called Jobs.

The error I am getting when I try to pass the `@job` object into my link is as follows:

```
  No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"jobs", :user_id=>1, :id=>nil}
```

Which clearly shows it can't find the id correctly and so is finding `nil`

At the moment I have my routes setup as so:

```
 resources :users do
   resources :jobs
 end
```

and the link I have is `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_job_path(@user.id,@job) %>`

What is interesting is that if I pass the object `@jobs` with an 's' on the end it will load the page correctly but when I click on the link will try and add all of that users job id's.

In my controller for edit I have:

```
def edit
 @user = current_user
 @job = @user.jobs.find(params[:id])
end
```

Any help really would be much appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

Okay I was defining the object on the wrong page of my controller (under edit instead of index). The issue I am now having is `Couldn't find Job without an ID`

I updated my controller index definition to:

```
 def index
  @user = current_user
  @jobs = @user.jobs.all
  @job = @user.jobs.find(params[:id])
 end
```

And have in my view (jobs#index)

```
<% @jobs.each do |f| %>
 ...
 <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_job_path(@user.id,job) %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated if you know where I am going wrong :)

Comment: can you post the rake routes output specifically for the edit_user_job path?  Also you are saying @user.id but not @job.id?

Comment: I've gotten this before. @job must be nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that `@job` is nil.

The link is to the edit path, and the controller code you've provided is from the edit action in the controller. It seems unlikely that the edit page links to itself.

Look at the code that's actually rendering that page (it will appear in your stack trace) and you'll find that @job is not set. I suspect that you are on the index page and have something like:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  ...
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_job_path(@user.id,@job) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If that is the case, then the link should be to `job`, not `@job`, i.e.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_job_path(@user.id,job) %>
```

Comment: Thanks iHiD, you are correct I am defining the objects on the wrong page in my controller. However now that I have defined things (answer updated above), I keep getting `Couldn't find Job without an ID` - do you know where I am going wrong on this? Thanks

Comment: You don't need the line `@job = @user.jobs.find(params[:id])` at all. You're listing all the jobs. You don't need to find one individual one.

Answer (score 1):

(expanding on iHiD's comment with his own post)

Using the restful resources means that you are going with the rails defaults, which consequently means that the index page gives you a list of all Jobs, and by default no single special job. If you run `rake routes` from the command line, you get all the routes, with parameters that are set from the URI. It should give you something like this:

```
user_jobs GET    /users/:user_id/jobs(.:format)          jobs#index
```

As you can see, there is no :id (params[:id]) for the index action.